# How to return a struct node pointer in linked list

Tags: c, function, return, nodes, singly-linked-list

```
int position(int key)
{
 struct node *new=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 struct node *p1=head;
 while(p1->info!=key&&p1->link!=NULL)
 p1=p1->link;

 return struct node *p1;
}

void insertafter()
{
 struct node *new=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 struct node *p1=head;
 p1=position();
}
```

I want to return the value of p1 in the function position to insertafter().So what is the return type of position since it is returning a struct node and how should I give the return statement.
Key is the value after which i have to insert the new node.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're on the right track! However, there are a few corrections that need to be made.

In the `position` function, you should handle the case when `head` is `NULL` to avoid dereferencing a null pointer. Additionally, you don't need to allocate memory for `new` in this function. Here's the corrected `position` function:

```
    struct node* position(int key)
    {
        struct node *p1 = head;
    
        while (p1 != NULL && p1->info != key)
            p1 = p1->link;
    
        return p1;
    }
```

In the `insertafter` function, make sure to handle the case when `position` returns `NULL` (indicating the key was not found). Also, it's essential to allocate memory for `new` before using it. Here's the corrected `insertafter` function:

```
    void insertafter(int key)
    {
        struct node *new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (new == NULL) {
            perror("Memory allocation failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        struct node *p1 = position(key);
    
        if (p1 != NULL) {
            new->link = p1->link;
            p1->link = new;
        }
        else {
            printf("Key not found in the linked list.\n");
            free(new); // Free the allocated memory
        }
    }
```

Make sure to handle memory allocation and deallocation properly in your actual code. Additionally, initialize `head` properly and consider the case where the list is empty.

Comment: Why allocate a node if there's a possibility it will be unused? Perhaps code needs to be re-arranged a bit??? And, maybe ask the OP what _value_ should be stored in the new node if it is created?

Comment: yep i changed the code .The value which has to be stored in the new node is taken from the user.